# Which technology is the best to inform clients about server events immediately?

Tags: sockets, websocket, connection, connection-pooling, comet

I'm going to create a game.
At first it will be the browser game.
Later it will be APP (Android, iPhone game).

At the server side I use nginx, apache, php.

=================

I need to inform online players about different events.
For example: one user is attacked by another one. I should inform him about that immediately.

Classical AJAX can't wrong there. I've read some about comet, web sockets and some other technologies.
But I still can't understand, which solution is the best for me?
Please, help me with the decision.

Answer (score 1):

WebSocket should be the preferred option. It is a broadly supported technology.

It is a persistent, full duplex connection, compatible with all major browsers http://caniuse.com/websockets

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could try Server Sent Events.

with SSE, a constant connection is maintained, until the page is unloaded, if something goes wrong with the connection or if you close the connection manually.

everytime something happens, e.g. a player is being attacked, you send an `event` command to the client, which then takes action depending on the event data.

although it does not work in every browser yet, it is a technique you could try

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/ gives some further explaination on SSE and on how to set it up

Comment: SSE is not supported by any version of Internet Explorer

Comment: I am aware of that. In IE, longpolling can be used. with longpolling, a connection is held open until an event occurs. then the cnnection is closed, and a new one has te be opened again

Answer (score 0):

Go with WebSocket. Using this, you can handle both the data sent from client browsers to the server (e.g. "user A attacks user B") and data sent from the server over a single channel. This saves server resources - and having a single technology is better than two separate ones (AJAX + something for the back channel).

Additionally, there are libraries for WebSocket for Android and iOS, so you could also attach native clients there in the future.

Since you'll need to distribute events to multiple clients at once, using something like Publish & Subscribe on top of WebSocket would make sense.

I suggest taking a look at [Crossbar.io](http://crossbar.io) - it's an open source application router which does Publish & Subscribe out of the box.

Full disclosure: I work for Tavendo, the originators of the Crossbar.io open source project.